# How to escape "code" tag in an XML code block in DokuWiki

Tags: escaping, dokuwiki

In a DokuWiki page, I want to show part of an XML file as a highlighted syntax block using the `<code xml>` tag. The XML also contains a `<code></code>` tag, so DokuWiki detects it as the end of the block. For example:

```
<code xml>
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <root>
    <code>Some data</code><!-- The sintax highlighted block breaks here -->
  </root>
</code><!-- This one is actually the closing tag -->
```

Is there a way to escape the `</code>` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the file tag instead:

```
<file xml>
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <root>
    <code>Some data</code>
  </root>
</file>
```

Comment: It works as long as there is no `<code>` and `<file>` tags at a time.