# Dokuwiki: how to escape <file> tag in a XML code block

Tags: escaping, dokuwiki

In a DokuWiki page, I want to show the content of a XML file as a downloadable highlighted syntax block using the `<file xml example.xml>` syntax. XML also contains a `<file>...</file>` tag, so DokuWiki detects it as the end of the block. For example:

```
<file xml example.xml>
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <root>
    <file>...</file><!-- The syntax highlighted block breaks here -->
  </root>
</file><!-- This one is actually the closing tag -->
```

Is there a way to escape the `</file>` closing tag in XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't escape it. But you could use the `<code></code>` syntax instead to avoid the conflict.

See also [How to escape "code" tag in an XML code block in DokuWiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20800993/how-to-escape-code-tag-in-an-xml-code-block-in-dokuwiki/)

Comment: XML content should be downloadable so I can't accept this as an answer. Thanks for the hint though.

Comment: The code tag takes all the same parameters as the file tag. So you can make it downloadable just the same.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. It works this way. I didn't expect those tags are virtually the same (and didn't read the docs carefully).